# Angular and Rxjs: writing unit test for filtering on Subject

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, rxjs, angular2-services

I have a method in an Angular service like below but I don't know how to write unit test for this function. Can anyone help me with this ? Thank you

```
message$: Subject<Message> = new Subject<Message>()
getMessage<T>(channel: string): Observable<T> {
    return this.message$.asObservable()
      .filter(m => m.channel === channel)
      .map(m => m.data)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's pseudo code. The actual code is left as an exercise.

```
Create an instance of the service
call getMessage('foo')
subscribe to the returned observable
store every event you receive in a variable receivedEvent

emit a message with the channel 'bar' from the subject
check that receivedEvent is still null

emit a message with the channel 'foo' from the subject
check that receivedEvent contains the data of the message you just emitted
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I managed to write the test and indeed it works. It took a bit time for me to understand the line "store every event you receive in a variable receivedEvent"

Comment: I'm having trouble with the same thing.  Could you add your final code?